# How to test answers to Django questions at stackoverflow

Tags: python, django

To all Djangonauts at stackoverflow:

Due to the way django works a minimal working sample is usually big (view, model, url, ...).
Therefore almost no question does provide such.

This results in answers that cannot be good tested because some part of the code is missing.

In my case it leads to answering almost only python questions because they're often testable.

What is the best way to test django answers?
Do you only use your experience or is there a trick for quick testing pieces of code (eg. a single view without knowing the model and urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use my experience, search for references to provide for questioner and ask them to provide something I think it has something to do with the error/issue.

It take a lot of time when communicate back and forth but there is no way we can reproduce the error because the question sometime missing a lot of information which might be a root cause of the issue. So I just go with the traceback of the issue and what questioner looking for.

[Django repo](https://github.com/django/django) also a place I visit a lot when trying to find some reference and it's always there. The answers can be right or wrong but it's depend on the perspectives of each answerer, questioner will confirm your answers and choose the right one after all.